# Blender playhead problem

Tags: interface

Frame number and playhead not lined up. Using 3.6 and had the same problem in 3.5.
Screenshot shows frame number above a keyframe, and that's correct. But the playhead is further back and doesn't even line up with a frame. This is making it difficult to animate.

Is there a preference somewhere that fixes this?

[image: Screenshot of frame number and playhead not lining up.]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [Works fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/Zdg3PWh.png)

Comment: Maybe you've tweaked the Output > Frame Range > Time Stretching?

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have tweaked the *Time Stretching* in the *Output* panel > *Frame Range*. It is used to slow down or speed up your animation speed:

[image]

Comment: Damn. That was it. I have no idea when I time-stretched.
Thanks much.